# php explanation on assertEquals

Tags: php, mysql, phpunit

Inside of a phpunit test I have a `$column` variable and `$actual` fetches a `$result` from a mysql query. Is it possible to simply explain what the below `assertEquals` statement is doing with the given info without showing all the code?

```
$column = 'access_level';

$this->assertEquals($column, $actual['access_level']);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.assertions.assertEquals

```
assertEquals(mixed $expected, mixed $actual[, string $message = ''])
```

> Reports an error identified ... if the two variables $expected
>   and $actual are not equal.

Which means in your case that reports an error if `$column != $actual['access_level']`